# Does it make sense to create a class just to store member variables for subclasses to use?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Currently, I have the following classes where there are 2 different types of solvers for each class that I have. Therefore, I have decided to design my classes as such:

```
// My two interfaces

class Type1Solver {
    virtual void solve() = 0;
}

class Type2Solver {
    virtual string solve(string) = 0;
}


// Implementing the interfaces
class XType1 : public Type1Solver {
    void solve() override; // Implemented in .cpp
}

class XType2 : public Type2Solver {
    string solve(string) override; // Implemented in .cpp
}

// And so on for other class A, B, C ...
```

The issue is both `XType1` and `XType2` uses the same variables since they are also `X` class. In that case what I was thinking of doing is as follows:

```
class X {
protected:
    unordered_map<string, string> some_data;
}

// Doing multiple inheritance so my specific X solvers can 
// utilize the protected variables in X in their solve() methods.

class XType1 : public Type1Solver, public X {
    void solve() override; // Implemented in .cpp
}

class XType2 : public Type2Solver, public X {
    string solve(string) override; // Implemented in .cpp
}
```

Question is, is this use of multiple inheritance valid? Does it break OOP / SOLID Principles. And alternatively, would it be a better case to make a helper class:

```
namespace XHelper {
    unordered_map<string, string> some_data = ...
}
```

Which I then import and utilize?

Comment: A general OO principle is to prefer *composition* over *inheritance* but you seem to have found a way to substitute *composition* for *inheritance*. So what you are doing does not look like a good idea to me. Inheritance relationships are strongly coupled but the goal of OOP (and generic programming in general) is *code reuse* and that generally means to find the most loosely coupled relationships possible.

Comment: Hi, the issue I have is that:
I might have some class A that only uses Type1Solver, B that only uses Type2Solver & C that uses both. So while using composition solves my problem of overlapping data structures that both solvers might use, it opens the problem in Strategy Pattern, where I'm unable to switch between my classes since some class hold 1 or 2 solvers (unless I implement it in such a way where the unneeded solver returns a default value?).

My original code uses Strategy Pattern to switch between the different Solver1 classes and same for Solver2

Comment: I think it is okay. Multiple inheritance can get complicated with more levels, e.g. `AdvancedType1Solver` inheriting from `Type1Solver` and `AdvancedX` inheriting from `X` and `AdvancedXType1` inheriting from `XType1`. Then you cannot easily reuse code and inheritance relationships. In those cases, it is recommended to have one interface side as pure abstract base classes (which you specify in each inheritance hierarchy newly), and the other side as implementation side, where functions are inherited to improve code reuse. Your clean separation of interface and implementation adheres to that.

Comment: But it always depends on which code or data definitions you want to reuse, how your code is called or its class instances stored (e.g. as base class when the dynamic class is only known at runtime or use templated code instead). Also are interfaces and class boundaries exposed at libraries, which are not recompiled, when internals change, or is the complete codebase recompiled. How much would you plan to extend the code? With direct changes or with inheritance? How much is the data and code coupled to each other? Can you abstract? How large is it? How much do Type1Solver and Type2Solver share?

Comment: I'd call it `SolverData` and made it member variable in both classes.